# Cannot run/debug maven app-client project in Netbeans 8.1

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans, maven-plugin

I have created a new Maven EE project in Netbeans containing :

- EAR Module
- EJB Module
- Web Module
- App-Client module (using [ACR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-acr-plugin/))
- Jar module containing the eJB interface.

Netbeans will not allow me to run the app-client module (the run button is greyed out). If I change `<packaging>app-client</packaging>` to `<packaging>jar</packaging>` the run option becomes available but no `@EJB` injection occurs.

Maven project POM :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
  <artifactId>Automate</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Automate</name>
  <modules>
    <module>Automate-ear</module>
    <module>Automate-web</module>
    <module>Automate-ejb</module>
    <module>Automate-common</module>
    <module>Automate-client</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

EAR Project POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>Automate</artifactId>
        <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
    <artifactId>Automate-ear</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <name>Automate-ear</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <modules>

                        <ejbModule>
                            <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>Automate-ejb</artifactId>
                        </ejbModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>Automate-web</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                        <appClientModule>
                            <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>Automate-client</artifactId>
                        </appClientModule>
                        <jarModule>
                            <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>Automate-common</artifactId>
                        </jarModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
            <artifactId>Automate-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
            <artifactId>Automate-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
            <artifactId>Automate-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>app-client</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
            <artifactId>Automate-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

App-Client POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>Automate</artifactId>
        <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>sotec.supervision.automate</groupId>
    <artifactId>Automate-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>app-client</packaging>

    <name>Automate-client</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sotec.supervision.automate</groupId>
            <artifactId>Automate-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-acr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>                            
                            <mainClass>example.automate.client.Main</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

EJB POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>Automate</artifactId>
    <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

    <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
    <artifactId>Automate-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>Automate-ejb</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
            <artifactId>Automate-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                    <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

JAR POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
        <artifactId>Automate</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>Automate-common</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

WAR POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>Automate</artifactId>
    <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

    <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
    <artifactId>Automate-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Automate-web</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>example.automate</groupId>
            <artifactId>Automate-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```